# Quickest algorithm/methods to find a varying string within a constant string?

Tags: java, string, search

With the title I mean that the public class declaration is always the same but the name varies:

`public class <class name>`

I'm wanting to search Java source code (in a JTextArea) for the public class.

So first it will find:

`public class Example1` or `public class Example2` or `public class Example3`

etc..

Then I want to store the String `Example1` or `Example2` or `Example3`

This program will be written in Java.

Can anyone help me out?

UPDATE:

Had a little go, very new to the Pattern and Matcher class.

```
private String findPublicClass() {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*public\\s+class\\s+(\\w+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(txtSource.getText());
    String s = null;
    boolean found = false;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        s = matcher.group(1);
        found = true;
    }
    if(!found)
        System.out.println("No public class found.");
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Have you written any code thus far? If not, I suggest giving it your best shot, and then coming back here with some example code, so we can better help you, and so we know you at least tried.

Comment: @Franklin I had a little go.

Answer (score 3):

My advice would be to follow the [lessons on Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) from the Java tutorials.

Comment: I agree, use a pattern and capture to find and get the information your looking for.  It's much faster than doing `substring` comparisons

Comment: Just looking over, this looks like a good approach, I'll try to conjure something up and post what I get.

Comment: @mthmulders I had a quick go, but I am new to it.

Comment: @mthmulders Am I close now?

Answer (score -1):

As just the name is varying the constant part is "public class " which has a fixed length say 10. So you can always get your class name by using substring(10).

Hope that helps.

EDIT:

Sample code

```
If(line.contains("public class"))
  return line.substring(10);
```

Comment: Yes but there may be imports/package declarations?

Comment: Can somebody exaplin sownvote , why is this answer not useful?

Comment: Actually @Lokesh made a valid answer in light of the question, I would just not hardcode (10) because the location may vary and use a position function.  But I also got a -1 for a valid answer, who knows :) we have a newbie that doesn't appreciate people answering?

Comment: @Lokesh Sure. You needed ~1,5 full lines of text to tell why it's `10` and not `15` or `4` or `-1`. Code should be as simple as it can be. When someone will need to find **private class** should he be using `line.substring(10)` as well? Hard to say - he'd need to think about it, or just **ask you**. Do you like to answer unneeded questions? :) If not, yours code should document itseft. You need to show the connection between `public class` and yours `10`. THEN you would know that this value isn't equal to 10...

Answer (score -1):

Well, a quick and dirty and very fast approach would be to read the string with a loop running from location 0 to L-1 (length), and have an index "i" stating how many characters were matched.

Every time a character is matched you would i++, otherwise i=0;

This way when i equals the length of the looked-for string, you will have a match.  The remainder is the other part (variable part) you are looking for.

Hope this helps!